# Acumatica Add a tool tip for text box control

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way in Acumatica to add a tool tip to a text box control on a form?
For example I would like to display a tool tip when the user hovers over the tax code control. Tax Code: [ 1099 ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example with usage of ToolTip. Take a look:

```
<px:PXDropDown ID="edStatus" runat="server" AllowNull="False" DataField="Status" Enabled="False" ToolTip="Some status"  ></px:PXDropDown>
```

[image: tool tip screen shot]

Or exactly your tool tip:

```
<px:PXDropDown ID="edStatus" runat="server" AllowNull="False" DataField="Status" Enabled="False" ToolTip="Tax Code: [ 1099 ]"  ></px:PXDropDown>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can conditional logic be added to display a different tool tip based on the value of the field?

Comment: Of what I know you can use javascript for conditional logic.

Comment: I'm new to Acumatica, How can the value of the field be referenced in  code, in your example within PXDropDown. I did not find anything  Acumatica documentation.